# VBA memory leak when looping through active workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA so please bear with some of my bad coding. But I seem to have a problem with my memory. After running this for a while, the program slows down significantly and my RAM gets eaten up by Excel. I've searched everywhere for a solution and tried many things including clearing variables, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any solutions?

In this code, I'm basically loading in a text file line by line into cells, and saving that text file after this specific plug in fetches some data from some API.

```
Sub test()

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim PathIn As String
Dim PathOut As String
Dim FileIn As String
Dim FileOut As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

PathIn = "somepath1"
PathOut = "somepath2"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(PathIn)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    FileIn = PathIn + oFile.Name
    FileOut = PathOut + oFile.Name

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileIn For Input As #FileNum

    i = 1
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
    j = 1
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        For j = 1 To 44
            Cells(i, j) = Split(DataLine, "|")(j)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    wb.SaveAs Filename:= _
        FileOut, FileFormat:= _
        xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    Set wb = Nothing

Close #FileNum
Next oFile

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks fine - maybe your add-in is the problem?

Comment: VBA is garbage-collected, so memory leaks are rare. Nothing jumps out in your code as being particularly problematic.

Comment: How large are your text files? BTW you can transfer the array for each line directly instead of using a loop `Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 44).Value = Split(DataLine, "|")`

Comment: Doesn't look like you clear the sheet between files?  If they're not all the exact same size that might cause problems.